# Why does Homebrew seem to require a /Developer folder with the Snow Leopard SDK?

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

I've had Xcode for a while (since Snow Leopard), and I installed Homebrew relatively recently (I currently have version 0.9.3). After an update to Xcode that recommended running an `uninstall-developer-folder` script, `brew doctor` fails with

```
Error: No such file or directory - /Developer
```

I've tried changing the path to the Xcode directory with `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, followed by `brew update`, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. I've also tried to recreate `/Developer` and symlink everything it needs there, but I got stuck at

```
Error: No such file or directory - /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

My copy of the Snow Leopard SDK was removed along with `/Developer` and I can't find and installer for it that supports Mountain Lion.

My friend installed Homebrew at around the same time as I did (he currently has version 0.9.2). He installed Xcode much more recently, and so never had a `/Developer` directory. He hasn't had any problems with Homebrew; `brew doctor` comes up clean for him.

Both machines run Mountain Lion and have the latest version of Xcode and Xcode's command-line tools. Why does my copy of Homebrew require `/Developer` and the Snow Leopard SDK, and how do I make it work without them?

Comment: Did you use `xcode-select` to point to the correct installation path?

Comment: I did, just now (and updated the question). `brew doctor` still complains for lack of `/Developer`.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message pls?

Comment: @iltempo Updated the question.